# Using margin-top to place link on top of simple img tag

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

JSBin example here: http://jsbin.com/okosox/1/edit

---

I just want to use `margin-top` to position a styled link on top of the image. I can position the link in the right place, but the background of the link is overwritten by the image itself.

In my example above, I positioned the link just above/below it so you can see how it should look like.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add `position: relative` to your `.album-link`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the .side-box div

```
position:relative;
```

and .album-link

```
position:absolute;
```